# Put "ALL" on ComboBox[0] so that we filter it. NOTE: ComboBox has data from DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox, filter

For example, I have a Combo box with these contents coming from the database using SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter and DataTable:

```
Japan
UK
USA
Philippines
```

Now, I want to add another choices. It should look like this:

```
----ALL----
Japan
UK
USA
Philippines
```

- If I chose Japan, it will filter and show all the landmarks in the country like Mt. Fuji, Tokyo Tower.
- If I chose UK, it will filter and show Big Ben, Westminster, Olympic Stadium.
- If I chose USA, it will show fat people, Kim Kardashian.
- IF I CHOSE ----ALL----, IT WILL SHOW ALL THE LANDMARKS FROM ALL COUNTRIES.

How do I do this? I'm using C# & SQL Server.

EDIT:
This is how I fill a combo box.

> _con.Open();
>
> ```
>         SqlCommand _viewLandmarks = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectDevices_AddingForm", _con);
>         _viewDevices.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>         _viewDevices.ExecuteNonQuery();
>
>         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(_viewLandmarks);
>         DataTable dTable = new DataTable("LANDMARK");
>         da.Fill(dTable);
>         comboModel.DataSource = dTable;
>         comboModel.DisplayMember = "Landmark";
>         comboModel.ValueMember = "LandmarkID";
>
>         _con.Close();
> ```

Comment: Show how do you bind your combobox. Usually it is enough to add the item `ALL` to your datasource before the bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments it is just a matter to add a fake record in your returned datatable

```
    _con.Open();
    SqlCommand _viewLandmarks = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectDevices_AddingForm", _con);
    _viewDevices.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _viewDevices.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(_viewLandmarks);
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable("LANDMARK");
    da.Fill(dTable);
    DataRow fakeRow = dTable.NewRow();
    fakeRow["Landmark"] = "(ALL)";
    fakeRow["LandmarkID"] = -1;
    dTable.Rows.Add(fakeRow);

    comboModel.DataSource = dTable;
    comboModel.DisplayMember = "Landmark";
    comboModel.ValueMember = "LandmarkID";

    _con.Close();
```

I have added the open/close parenthesys around ALL to to force the new added row to the beginning of your datatable (assuming that it is sorted by Landmark).
Notice also that this approach assumes also that your fields are all NULLABLE. If one or more fields doesn't allow null values you need to set an appropriate value before adding the fakeRow to the Datatale rows collection

Answer (score 0):

Just add a row in your datatable before binding and set the value to All.

Comment: How do I do that? Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a example of binding the combo box

```
 private void BindCombo()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = GetDataTable();
        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
        row["Value"] = "0";
        row["Name"] = "All";
        dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: @  Daniel Barga. I have given you just a sample. Here GetDataTable() is a method which gets the values from DB. And the idea is to add a row to datatable and bind it to combobox.